# How to add tooltip on the logo in Twilio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to display a tooltip when user hover mouse over the logo. Not sure if it's possible to achieve that in Twilio.

```html
flex.MainHeader.defaultProps.logoUrl = `https://${serviceBaseUrl}/assets/MyApp.png`;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to use the onMouseOver and onMouseOut event handlers to toggle the visibility of the tooltip when the logo is hovered over. You can add these event handlers to the img element that represents the logo, and use them to set the state of the component that renders the tooltip. The state would contain a boolean value that indicates whether the tooltip should be visible or not, and the render method of the component would use this value to conditionally render the tooltip.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showTooltip: false };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          src={flex.MainHeader.defaultProps.logoUrl}
          onMouseOver={() => this.setState({ showTooltip: true })}
          onMouseOut={() => this.setState({ showTooltip: false })}
        />
        {this.state.showTooltip && <div>This is the tooltip</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This way the tooltip will only be visible when the user hover the mouse over the logo.